# How do I set the resolution in Flutter's Camera package

Tags: flutter, dart, camera

I'm working on a flutter app that is using the [Camera package's](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) camera preview.

I'm initializing the camera controller like so:

```
final controller = CameraController(
  _cameras[0],
  ResolutionPreset.ultraHigh,
  enableAudio: false,
  imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.bgra8888,
);
```

The `ResolutionPreset` enum has these options:

```
enum ResolutionPreset {
  /// 352x288 on iOS, 240p (320x240) on Android
  low,

  /// 480p (640x480 on iOS, 720x480 on Android)
  medium,

  /// 720p (1280x720)
  high,

  /// 1080p (1920x1080)
  veryHigh,

  /// 2160p (3840x2160)
  ultraHigh,

  /// The highest resolution available.
  max,
}
```

The resolution needs to be `4032x2034`. How do I use a custom resolution?

Comment: Why not use max available resolution? Not all devices will be able to handle your custom resolution, what happens to that? You should just use the maximum available for the device and scale/crop as needed to fit the resolution you need.

Comment: Warning! you can currently set the resolution to high (720p), if you use flutter camera package. see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78247

Answer (score 0):

[ResolutionPreset](https://pub.dev/documentation/camera_platform_interface/latest/camera_platform_interface/ResolutionPreset.html) enum doesn't provide the option to set a custom resolution. As a workaround, you can use `ResolutionPreset.max` then resize the image. Using the [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) package, you can resize the image to the desired `width` and `height` and write it on storage.

```
// Read a jpeg image from file path
Image image = decodeImage(File('image path').readAsBytesSync());

// Resize the image
Image resizedImage = copyResize(image, width: 4032, height: 2034);

// Save the image as jpg
File('out/image-resized.jpg')
    ..writeAsBytesSync(encodeJpg(resizedImage, quality: 100));
```

Comment: My question is in regard to CameraPreview, not loading files

Answer (score -1):

The only way you can do it is change cameraController value in runtime.

Let's start with constructing and initialization:

```
CameraController cameraController = CameraController(cameras[0], 
    ResolutionPreset.low, enableAudio: false); // the state field 

@override
void initState() {
   cameraController.initialize();
   // ...
}
```

After that you can change the dependency like that:

```
 _changeResolution() async {
    cameraController = CameraController( cameras[0], 
          ResolutionPreset.veryHigh, // new resolution
              enableAudio: false);
    await cameraController.initialize(); // initialize again
    setState(() {}); // changes UI
 }
```

Comment: That didn't answer the question. I want a custom resolution not in `ResolutionPreset`